# Excel Export With Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, excel, razor

I have a this code for excel export from database using MVC.

This code working on Index view but if the code in different ActionResult with parameters ( ajax post data ) not working. I can get values using ajax, I can create DataTable from database, datatable can write to excel but not downloading.

Using ClosedXML for excel export.

What can I do for it ?

Thanks for your help.

```
 string constr =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers"))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.xlsx");
                    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Ömür instead of using ajax post method, try the below code . you can also pass parameters with location.href.

```
 <input type="button" value="Export" id="btnExport"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $("#btnExport").click(function f(){
    location.href = '@Url.Action("Export","ControllerName")';
});
</script>
```

code at controller

```
  public void Export()
    { 
string constr=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers"))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.xlsx");
                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can  return a stream inorder to download the file in response using the stream

Here is the example:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "C Sharp corner", "United States");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Suraj", "India");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Test User", "France");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Developer", "Russia");
            //Exporting to Excel
            string folderPath = "C:\\Excel\\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
            }
            //Codes for the Closed XML
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");

                //wb.SaveAs(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.xlsx");
                string myName = Server.UrlEncode("Test" + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() +          ".xlsx");
                MemoryStream stream = GetStream(wb);// The method is defined below
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myName);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
                Response.End();
            }
```

### GetStream method:

```
public MemoryStream GetStream(XLWorkbook excelWorkbook)
        {
            MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
            excelWorkbook.SaveAs(fs);
            fs.Position = 0;
            return fs;
        }
```

Source: http://surajpassion.in/create-an-excel-file-using-closedxml/

Hope it will solve your problem.

Thanks

Karthik